# Guide to Modular Forms

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, modular-forms

I recently found more and more interest in number theory, and I am especially intrigued by elliptic curves and modular forms.

I bought the title "A First Course in Modular Forms", without looking in an online pdf (which might not exist), because I expected something rather basic.

But I think I am lacking preleminaries, especially from complex analysis.

What would a natural guide to modular forms look like? Should I first get some basic knowledge about complex analysis, or working through Serre's "A course in arithmetic" first, which assumes again complex analysis in the 2nd half.

Besides that, what would be an introduction text on these topics.
Is Husemöller "Elliptic curves" a good starting point?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not familiar with complex analysis, then I recommend Stein and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis*, since the last few chapters is essentially about modular forms, but only for the powers of theta functions, to answer the questions about sum of squares of integers. If I remember correctly, the book also contains a proof of the prime number theorem by means of using zeta functions, which could be another interesting part for you. After that, Zagier's *Elliptic modular forms* chapter in his book *123 of modular forms* could also be a great reference for the amazing applications of modular forms.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Valuable recommandations! I will definitly take a look at this.